# After El Capitan upgrade synch does not work on texshop

Tags: mactex, texshop, mac

I have installed el Capitan on mac. After reinstalling TeX and TeXshop synch doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Reconfiguring TexStudio after upgrade to OS X El Capitan deals with TeXStudio. I was asking about TeXShop. The fixes mentioned for TexStudio don't work for me.

Comment: Ok, could you provide additional information/error, please?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, open **preferences** in TexShop settings, then under the **Engine** page specify the following path: `/Library/TeX/texbin` instead of the previous `/usr/texbin`. 
Then, at the end, save the new setting by pressing ok.

Comment: I tried but this does not fix the problem